# Elisp how to feed a subprocess with commands with process-send-string before it quits

Tags: emacs, elisp

Code:

```
(progn
   (start-process "my-process" "my-process-output" "bash")
   (process-send-string "my-process" "ls -al ~"))
```

When ran, I only got

```
bash-3.2$
```

Has "my-process" terminated before "process-send-string"? My goal isn't particularly to issue commands to a "bash" process. It's actually more general - that's to use process-send-string to feed commands to an existing subprocess. I've tried to pass nil arguments to start-process in the hope that emacs somehow initiates a process-place holder for me before it gets passed to any concrete arguments but that didn't help either.

```
(progn
   (start-process "my-process" "my-process-output" nil)
   (process-send-string "my-process" "bash -c \"ls -al ~\""))
```

What's the approach to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with a newline (press enter) after typing your `ls` command:

```
(process-send-string "my-process" "ls -al ~\n"))
```